# Deploying a blackberry application to a Physical device

Tags: blackberry, mobile

---

I had developed a blackberry application in Sybase Unwired Platform with SAP ECC 6.0 as the backend data source. Now I need to deploy this application to the physical device. Can anybody please help me to deploy my application to a physical device with a step by step procedure? I need to know what are all the things that we need to complete the step of Registration, Signing and Deploying.

---

Thanks and regards
Rinzy Deena Mathews.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this : [what are the steps required to run a blackberry application created for the blackberry device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726403/what-are-the-steps-required-to-run-a-blackberry-application-created-on-a-blackber)

This will give you some idea on the topic